# "Couldn't load the data for this visual" Power BI for one user

Tags: powerbi

I have one end user who is receiving the error "Couldn't retrieve the data for this visual. Please try again later.

We have checked that this user has permissions to the data model and to the reports. Has anyone else experienced this error for one specific user?

Thank you so much for your help.

Nikki